# NSURLConnection async thread connection closure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I used NSURLConnection to get some data from internet in thread seperated from the main thread:
I put this in my ***JSONViewController.h*** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JSONViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
   BOOL firstTime;
   NSMutableData *_responseData;
}
@end
```

I use this code to start the connection in ***JSONViewController.m***:

```
NSURLRequest *request;
 if (self.jsonItem == nil) {
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",MY_URL,@"testvalue"]]];
  }else {
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",MY_URL,(NSString *)self.jsonItem]]];
  }
  NSLog(@"json Item = %@",self.jsonItem);


  // Create url connection and fire request
  NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I implement also those functions which are related to NSURLConnection protocol as well:

```
#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
```

Everything works well.
The question is: after I get the result and the connection should be finished, Why do I still see this small indicator near the carrier field above the navigation bar? should I stop the connection manually ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you should find something like this:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

That sets the status bar's activity indicator to 'on'. 
When the loading is finished you need to turn it off again. Do so by:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

If you are downloading not more than one file at a time, then just add the two lines to your `connectionDidFinisLoading` and `didFailWithError` method implementations.

Comment: my fear was that the connection still working in the background. Thank you :)

Comment: It certainly isn't if you receive the call to one of these methods.

Comment: Theoretically you could have fired multiple connections in parallel. For each of them one of these methods will get called.

Answer (score 1):

You may hide it by this simple line

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the start method, place your function method:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

... and in the finish, place in `connectionDidFinisLoading` and `connectiondidFailWithError`:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Hope this helps!